# Params for joy_teleop package?

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, rosrun, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am a beginner  to ros and I am trying to publish messages to cmd_vel with the joy_teleop package. The problem is this: in the code it says this:

```
 Generic joystick teleoperation node.
Will not start without configuration, has to be stored in 'teleop' parameter.
See config/joy_teleop.yaml for an example.
```

Problem is I can't figure out what params I need to give it and I can't discern what I need to pull from the yaml file. Could someone please supply me with a example rosrun line to start this node with a xbox 360 controller?
Thanks,
Luketheduke

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205495/params-for-joy_teleop-package?/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some googling brought me to [teleop_tools/issues/10](https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_tools/issues/10), where the author points to [reem_robot/reem_bringup/launch/joystick_teleop.launch](https://github.com/pal-robotics/reem_robot/blob/a22cfdbe7dcf2cc533ad8954f0430ff0ffbb86c8/reem_bringup/launch/joystick_teleop.launch) for an example launch file. That file refers to [reem_robot/reem_bringup/config/joy_teleop.yaml](https://github.com/pal-robotics/reem_robot/blob/df7e7973de1207c99a6cfb1a5c4c89bff863f49a/reem_bringup/config/joy_teleop.yaml), which should give you some clue as to how to configure things for your particular joystick.

Note that the author of `joy_teleop` adds the following in [teleop_tools/issues/10](https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_tools/issues/10):

> joy_teleop is subscribing to the `/joy` topic to provide high level functionalities. Unless you have a driver for your joystick it won't do any good.

---

Edit: also, I think the [teleop_twist_joy](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy) is better suited for what you want to do. [joy_teleop](http://wiki.ros.org/joy_teleop) is a higher level package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-03-21**:
Ok thanks I am now using teleop_twist_joy but would you happen to know why my node requires the values for linear and turning to be extremely high(around 30)?
Thanks,
Luketheduke
edit:
I figured out the problem is in my node. teleop_twist_joy is working fine for me.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-29**:
I don't really know. Have you verified that the interface you have to your hardware is correctly transforming / converting input? Just thinking out loud, but `Twists` use radians for the rotational parts, have you converted those properly?